# Spring Boot with Java 8 Date format

Tags: java, spring-boot

I trying to use java 8 LocalDate with springboot

I put

```
compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
```

int .gradle

and

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate dia;
```

in properties I have:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

but dont work, when I try to post I got this error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "02/09/2015 11:32:15",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read document: Text '10/10/2015' could not be parsed at index 0 (through reference chain: br.com.lumera.entity.Feriado[\"dia\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '10/10/2015' could not be parsed at index 0 (through reference chain: br.com.lumera.entity.Feriado[\"dia\"])",
  "path": "/atos/feriado/"
}
```

how can I fix this?

tks

Answer (score 0):

By default, the format accepted by the `LocalDateDeserializer` class is yyyy-mm-dd. You'll have to modify your frontend component so it formats the date accordingly. If you want to specify a different format in the Serializer/Deserializer, you'll have to instantiate it with your custom `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`